# Displaying unique name with total of column value in a group with additional variables in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning Python and thought working on a project might be the best way to learn it. I have about 200,000 rows of data in which the data shows list of medication for the patient. Here's a sample of the data.

```
PTID PTNAME     MME   DRNAME       DRUGNAME                    SPLY STR QTY  FACTOR
1   PATIENT, A  2700    DR, A   OXYCODONE HCL 15 MG             30  15  120 1.5
1   PATIENT, A  2700    DR, B   OXYCODONE HCL 15 MG             30  15  120 1.5
2   PATIENT, B  4050    DR, C   MORPHINE SULFATE ER 15 MG       30  15  270 1
2   PATIENT, B  4050    DR, C   MORPHINE SULFATE ER 15 MG       30  15  270 1
2   PATIENT, B   840    DR, A   OXYCODONE-ACETAMINOPHE 10MG-32  14  10  56  1.5
2   PATIENT, B  1350    DR, C   OXYCODONE-ACETAMINOPHE 5 MG-32  15  5   180 1.5
3   PATIENT, C  1350    DR, C   OXYCODONE-ACETAMINOPHE 5 MG-32  15  5   180 1.5
3   PATIENT, C  1800    DR, D   OXYCODONE-ACETAMINOPHE 10MG-32  30  10  120 1.5
```

I've been thinking about this a lot and have tried many ways but none of the code produce any results or makes any sense. Honestly, I don't even know where to begin. A little help would be highly appreciated.

So, what I want to do is consolidate the data for each patients and calculate the `Total MME` for each patient. The `DRUGNAME` should show the one that has higher MME. In other words, the dataframe should only have one row for each patient.

One thing I did try is

```
groupby_ptname = semp.groupby('PTNAME').apply(lambda x: x.MME.sum())
```

which shows unique patient names with total MME,  but I'm not sure how to add other variables in this new dataframe.

Comment: please help us by making a [good  reproducible pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)  I am unable to paste your df into python no matter how I try.

Comment: Could you attach the excel sheet with the above data in it . I will be able solve this by converting it to dictionary , pandas not needed actually .

Comment: Sorry, I made the data up to protect privacy. I'll try to make the data reproducible. please bear with me, since I'm learning, I have to figure out how to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [62]: df.sort_values('MME').groupby('PTNAME').agg({'MME':'sum', 'DRUGNAME':'last'})
Out[62]:
                                  DRUGNAME    MME
PTNAME
PATIENT, A             OXYCODONE HCL 15 MG   5400
PATIENT, B       MORPHINE SULFATE ER 15 MG  10290
PATIENT, C  OXYCODONE-ACETAMINOPHE 10MG-32   3150
```

or with `.reset_index()`:

```
In [64]: df.sort_values('MME').groupby('PTNAME').agg({'MME':'sum', 'DRUGNAME':'last'}).reset_index()
Out[64]:
       PTNAME                        DRUGNAME    MME
0  PATIENT, A             OXYCODONE HCL 15 MG   5400
1  PATIENT, B       MORPHINE SULFATE ER 15 MG  10290
2  PATIENT, C  OXYCODONE-ACETAMINOPHE 10MG-32   3150
```

**UPDATE:** more fun with `agg()` function

```
In [84]: agg_funcs = {
    ...:     'MME':{'MME_max':'last',
    ...:            'MME_total':'sum'},
    ...:     'DRUGNAME':{'DRUGNAME_max_MME':'last'}
    ...: }
    ...:
    ...: rslt = (df.sort_values('MME')
    ...:          .groupby('PTNAME')
    ...:          .agg(agg_funcs)
    ...:          .reset_index()
    ...: )
    ...: rslt.columns = [tup[1] if tup[1] else tup[0] for tup in rslt.columns]
    ...:

In [85]: rslt
Out[85]:
       PTNAME  MME_total  MME_max                DRUGNAME_max_MME
0  PATIENT, A       5400     2700             OXYCODONE HCL 15 MG
1  PATIENT, B      10290     4050       MORPHINE SULFATE ER 15 MG
2  PATIENT, C       3150     1800  OXYCODONE-ACETAMINOPHE 10MG-32
```

Comment: This does the same thing as the answer above. This is also a good solution, although I didn't understand what's `last` in the `agg`?

Comment: It seems to me that this will pick the drug with the single largest MME as opposed to the largest total MME. Not sure anymore which one you need.

Comment: "Last" means pick the last row in the group. He/she is sorting by the MME value, so that picks the drug with the highest MME.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that too. Turned out this is the way I want it. I put two solutions together. @VictorChubukov solution shows the largest total MME. But Victor's solution helped me fix another problem too. I think this has been a great learning experience for me. I'll look at this more carefully and then select the answer appropriately.

Comment: This is very exciting. Thank you @VictorChubukov and @MaxU, your solutions have helped me learn a lot and challenge further. For this solution, I changed `'sum'` to a custom function by defining a function that calculates a 90 day average MME for each patient. Moving away from C# to Python definitely now. Thank you both.

Comment: @user1828605, `agg` is an aggregation function, which will be applied on results of `groupby`, operation;  `last` - picks last value for each group

Comment: @VictorChubukov, `this will pick the drug with the single largest MME` - yes, it'll pick one last `DRUGNAME` with a biggest MME (because of sorting) for __each group__. That's how i understood OPs question...

Comment: Literally, it's like you just read my mind. I was doing just that to show the last total_mme and the sum of total_mme.

Comment: @user1828605, i just wanted to show the flexibility of `agg()` method... ;)

Comment: I just wanted to say one thing. Because of this solution, I was able to eliminate about 27% of the patients from the list that the vendor inaccurately identified. This made me look good and learnt a lot along the way. So, credit to both MaxU and VictorChubukov

Answer (score 1):

Have another look at the documentation for the [pandas groupby methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Here's something that could work for you:

```
#first get the total MME for each patient and drug combination
total_mme=semp.groupby(['PTNAME','DRUGNAME'])['MME'].sum()
#this will be a series object with index corresponding to PTNAME and DRUGNAME and values corresponding to the total MME
#now get the indices corresponding to the drug with the max MME total
max_drug_indices=total_mme.groupby(level='PTNAME').idxmax()
#index the total MME with these indices
out=total_mme[max_drug_indices]
```

Comment: This is amazing. I think this is exactly what I needed. Will I be able to add any number of variables in the first group_by?

Comment: Sure. Just remember that if you do calculations on multiple columns, you will have to specify which one you want to take the `idxmax` of.

Comment: Is there a short-cut to use all columns instead of typing each one of them?

Comment: So, turned out, if I add all variables it will be like using groupby('PTNAME') i.e. it shows everything in groups without aggregating it. But I was able to pick only the ones I need and your solution still worked. I started breaking down the code and learnt a lot from it. Thank you.